# rake db:seed -> Mongoid::Errors::NoSessionConfig:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am building an application in ROR using SQLite.

In the project I include a gem which has run time dependency in Mongoid.

However for my case, I do not use mongoid or any mongodb.

When I am running rake db:seed which I use to fill the fields in my sql database I receive the specific error:

```
rake aborted!
```

Mongoid::Errors::NoSessionConfig: 
Problem:
  No configuration could be found for a session named 'default'.
Summary:
  When attempting to create the new session, Mongoid could not find a session configuration for the name: 'default'. This is necessary in order to know the host, port, and options needed to connect.
Resolution:
  Double check your mongoid.yml to make sure under the sessions key that a configuration exists for 'default'. If you have set the configuration programatically, ensure that 'default' exists in the configuration hash.

Comment: What is the gem that depends on Mongoid?

Comment: https://rubygems.org/gems/health-data-standards/versions/3.5.3   It is this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says pretty clearly in the [`health-data-standards` gem readme](https://github.com/projectcypress/health-data-standards) that:

> The Quality Measure engine relies on a MongoDB MongoDB running a
>   minimum of version 2.4.* or higher.

So if you intend on using the gem you will need to setup Mongodb and mongoid as well because it will store data in mongodb.

Using both a relational DB and mongoid in the same Rails app is technically possible but ups the complexity significantly. Also SQLite is only really suited for tiny apps or rapid prototyping.

So either switch gems or take the dive into mongoland (its fun, I promise)

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/
- http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#installation

Comment: yes you are right for what you are telling me. I used it like this, because I need a parser from it. Then I will use another ruby app which it will send the parsed file through web service in the other app where I will have only the SQLite. Yes I use SQLite, for rapid prototyping.

Comment: In that case the cleanest solution might be to pull the parser out of the health-data-standards gem using a [subtree split](https://makingsoftware.wordpress.com/2013/02/16/using-git-subtrees-for-repository-separation/) - provided the parser does not actually require mongoid.